# Consulta mysql multitabla y datos repetidos

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

primero que todo muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda, estoy aprendiendo php y consultas a base de datos y tengo algunas dudas, estoy realizando una consulta multitabla que es algo como lo siguiente:

```
SELECT t.Tourname, c.FechaConcierto, can.nombreCancion, b.nombreBanda, bi.nombreBandaInvitada, bi.nombreCantante
FROM Tour AS t
LEFT JOIN Concierto AS c
ON c.ConciertoID=t.TourID
LEFT JOIN Cancion AS can 
ON c.Canciones=can.cancionID
LEFT JOIN Bandas AS b
ON can.cancionID=b.BandaID
LEFT JOIN BandaInvitada AS bi 
ON can.cancionID=bi.bandaInvitadaID
LEFT JOIN Cantante AS ca 
ON bi.Cantante=ca.cantanteID
WHERE t.TourID = 2
ORDER BY c.FechaConcierto ASC;
```

La primera pregunta es si esta consulta está bien, como estoy aprendiendo no se si sea erronea, el inconveniente en general que tengo es que esta consulta me da resultados por ejemplo así:

```
Sol 12--10-16 Amame Null Los toños Pepe Sierra
Sol 12--10-16 La luz Null Los toños Pepe Sierra
Sol 12--10-16 No se Null Los toños Pepe Sierra
Sol 12--10-16 El pasado Null Los toños Pepe Sierra
Sol 12--10-16 Como fue Banda caravana Null Null
Sol 12--10-17 Amame Null Los toños Pepe Sierra
Sol 12--10-17 La luz Null Los toños Pepe Sierra
Sol 12--10-17 No se Null Los toños Pepe Sierra
Sol 12--10-17 El pasado Null Los toños Pepe Sierra
Sol 12--10-17 Como fue Banda caravana Null Null
```

Como se dan cuenta hay muchos datos que se repiten, no se si se pueda optimizar la consulta para que eso no pase o como ordenar el array o ejecutar el foreach para que los datos se muestren por ejemplo algo así:

```
Sol 
12--10-16
Los toños Pepe Sierra
    Amame (Cancion)
    La luz (Cancion)
    No se (Cancion)
    El pasado (Cancion)
Como fue (Cancion)
    Banda caravana

12--10-17
Los toños Pepe Sierra
    Amame (Cancion)
    La luz (Cancion)
    No se (Cancion)
    El pasado (Cancion)
Como fue (Cancion)
    Banda caravana
```

Muchas gracias por su colaboraciòn

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Creo que para tu caso la mejor opción sería hacer uso combinado de `GROUP_CONCAT` y de `GROUP BY`. Esto te permitirá agrupar en una sola columna, mediante un separador, el resultado de varias filas. Luego, por programación, puedes hacer un `split` de esas columnas para tratarlas como si fueran filas. Así, tendrás una columna como esta por ejemplo: `Amame|La Luz|No se|El Pasado`, y usarías el separador `|`  para presentar los datos como indicas en la pregunta. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](http://rextester.com/OGQOFP1481), observa cómo se genera la columna `titulos`.

Comment: Muchas gracias en serio, que cracks! me sirvió mucho, he utilizado el GROUP_CONCAT y me va super, me ha repetido los resultados pero con un DISTINCT y me arroja lo que quiero algo así: Sol 
-
12--10-16
12--10-17
-
Amame
La luz
No se
El pasado
Como fue
-
Los toños
-
Pepe Sierra
-
Banda caravana   Mi duda es cómo imprimo para que cada banda quede con su respectiva canción y cada cantante con su banda (puesto que puede haber null) ya que puede que una posición de una canción no corresponda con posición de una banda ,de un cantante o de una banda invitada por los campos null

Comment: Dentro del `GROUP_CONCAT` tú puedes usar también `ORDER BY` para que te ordene los valores que agrupará según uno o varios criterios tales como banda, nombre del artista, etc. Traté de hacerte un código de prueba pero en la pregunta no queda claro como están organizadas tus tablas. En la elaboración de la prueba pude ver que quizá haya algunas lagunas , por ejemplo, que pasa si hay un artista que pertenece a dos bandas, o si hay canciones que el artista toca solo, sin depender de la banda, etc. Tampoco veo clara la relación de Tour, con Concierto.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta esta bien, lo único que me extraña es que hagas un LEFT JOIN en vez de un JOIN normal, para evitar los resultados con `Null`, como por ejemplo:

```
Sol 12--10-16 Amame Null Los toños Pepe Sierra
```

Para formatear el resultado de salida, puedes usar la funcion `CONCAT`. Esta función te permite concatenar una lista de strings.

Un ejemplo utilizando tu consulta:

```
SELECT CONCAT("Tour": + t.Tourname, char(13), c.FechaConcierto + " - " + b.nombreBanda)
```

El resultado sería:

```
Tour:Sol 
12--10-16 - Banda caravana
```

MySQL ofrece muchas funciones para tratar los textos, [aquí tienes una lista con todas las funciones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)

Para hacer un salto de línea, he usado `CHAR(13)` tal como he leido en [este post de Stack OVerflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string), pero no he podido comprobar si funciona. En este mismo post también dicen de usar `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`, depende si trabajas en Windows o no.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, que genios son, usé el GROUP_CONCAT, me ha repetido los resultados pero con un DISTINCT me arroja lo que quiero, algo así: Sol - 12--10-16 12--10-17 - Amame La luz No se El pasado Como fue - Los toños - Pepe Sierra - Banda caravana. Tengo una nueva duda es cómo imprimo para que cada banda quede con su respectiva canción y cada cantante con su banda (puesto que puede haber null) ya que puede que una posición de una canción no corresponda con posición de una banda ,de un cantante o de una banda invitada por los campos null, muchas gracias